# Find an ouGroup plus all its members which Common Name contains given phrase in a single LDAP query

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have the following code:

```
private static DirectorySearcher GetSearcher(string domain, string ouGroup)
{
    var searchRoot = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ouGroup)
        ? new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}")
        : new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}/{ouGroup}");
    return new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
}
    public IReadOnlyList<AdGroup> FilterGroupAndMemebers(string domain, string ouGroupDistinguishedName, string filter)
{
    var result = new List<AdGroup>();

    var childGroupTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetChildGroups(domain, ouGroupDistinguishedName, filter))
        .ContinueWith(task => result.AddRange(task.Result));

    var membersTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetMemberGroups(domain, ouGroupDistinguishedName, filter))
        .ContinueWith(task => result.AddRange(task.Result));

    Task.WaitAll(childGroupTask, membersTask);

    return result;
}

public IReadOnlyList<AdGroup> GetMemberGroups(string domain, string ouGroupDistinguishedName, string filter)
{
    using (var searcher = GetSearcher(domain, null))
    {
        searcher.Filter = $"(&(cn=*{filter.Trim()}*)(memberOf={ouGroupDistinguishedName}))";
        searcher.Asynchronous = true;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("adspath");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectguid");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
        searcher.PageSize = 150;
        var searchResult = searcher.FindAll();

        using (searchResult)
        {
            return searchResult
                .OfType<SearchResult>()
                .Select(group =>
                {
                    return new AdGroup
                    {
                        Id = new Guid(group.Properties["objectguid"].OfType<byte[]>().First()),
                        Name = group.Properties["cn"].OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(),
                        Description = group.Properties["description"].OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(),
                    };
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

public IReadOnlyList<AdGroup> GetChildGroups(string domain, string ouGroupDistinguishedName, string filter)
{
    using (var searcher = GetSearcher(domain, ouGroupDistinguishedName))
    {
        searcher.Filter = $"(&(cn=*{filter.Trim()}*)(objectclass=group))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Asynchronous = true;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("adspath");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectguid");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
        searcher.PageSize = 150;
        var searchResult = searcher.FindAll();

        using (searchResult)
        {
            return searchResult
            .OfType<SearchResult>()
            .Select(group =>
            {
                return new AdGroup
                {
                    Id = new Guid(group.Properties["objectguid"].OfType<byte[]>().First()),
                    Name = group.Properties["cn"].OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(),
                    Description = group.Properties["description"].OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(),
                };
            })
            .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The link to the screen shot:
https://ibb.co/cQJmnp
So, in the attached picture you can see a group called ‘Sales UK’ and it’s a member of a group ‘Sales’. The ‘Sales UK’ is a child of the ‘OU=Groups’. They have different icons and I’m not entirely sure what kind of difference it makes. I call them both ‘AD groups’.
The ‘Sales’ group lays under a different AD group. The ‘Sales UK’ is linked to the ‘Sales’ via attribute called ‘memberOf’. When I’m searching for a group by CN I would like search in the group of all children plus all members(linked with memberOf attribute)
If I type ‘Sa’ phrase I expect to get the ‘Sales’ and the ‘Sales UK’ as a result. I’m doing two separate queries now. I’m wondering if there is a possibility to create only one query and merge those filters somehow.

Comment: Ou and groups are 2 different things IMO. Can you please elaborate more on what you mean by `ouGroup`? Also, can you also explain in detail your statement *"I would like to add some condition to be able to add a father oUGroup as well to the result."* - with some example, etc.

Comment: You can add condition for the second group and combine it with first condition using OR (|) operator. For example group members query using (|(name=A)(name=B)) filter will return all members of both group A and B